# how do I run a startup script to set my touchpad scroll speed on startup

Tags: scripts, touchpad, cron, startup

ive tried everything, crontab, setting it from a startup script like xinitrc, using the startup application option and running a script from there. but no matter what i do i always need to manually type sudo xinput set-prop 12 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 50 in my console on startup to set it to 50 ever new desktop session

please help

Comment: Do you really need to do the command with sudo? It should work in a desktop session as user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a systemd service ?

first get the ID of your input device, you can do this by running `xinput list`

then create a file like `/etc/systemd/system/dat_input_scroll_speed.service` with your favorite IDE like `sudo nano /etc/systemd/dat_input_scroll_speed.service`

and put this inside:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set input configuration on boot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinput set-prop 14 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 50

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then replace 14 by the id of the device you found earlier, then save the file, then enable this new service at startup with `sudo systemctl enable dat_input_scroll_speed.service`

Comment: did everything you successfully till sudo systemctl enable input-config.service
where then i get this output: Failed to enable unit: Unit file input-config.service does not exist.

Comment: my bad it was sudo systemctl enable dat_input_scroll_speed.service that you had to enter, I edited my answer